# What is the most recent non-primate ancestors of humans?

Tags: evolution

If we go down the evolutionary tree of humans, (*Homo sapiens*, *Homo erectus*, ...), what will be the first non-primate ancestors?

Comment: Note that humans did not evolve from the tree shrews, both they and we share a common ancestor. See [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/3304/1306) for more.

Comment: I see that you edited the question to include "ancestor". @terdon makes a very good point. We do not think of ancestors in the fossil record in the same way that a person has ancestors (parents, grandparents, etc.). The most recent common ancestor of primates and tree shrews is neither a primate nor a tree shrew. There is no name for that taxon.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Tree of Life](http://tolweb.org/Eutheria/15997), tree shrews ([Scandentia](http://tolweb.org/Scandentia/15964)) are the sister group to Primates. So Scandentia are the most closely related extant mammals that are not Primates. Here's an image:

[image]